# Programmatically check fixnum size

Tags: common-lisp

[Wikibook for Common Lisp](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Common_Lisp/Advanced_topics/Numbers#Fixnums_and_Bignums) says that fixnums are guaranteed to be able to hold integer values in [-2<sup>15</sup>; 2<sup>15</sup>-1] range and that it is implementation dependent. `*features*` can tell me if the host is 32 or 64-bit but a fixnum in Lisp [does not cover the whole 32/64 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106597/why-are-fixnums-in-emacs-only-29-bits/107649#107649). Is there a way to programmatically check what is the size of a fixnum in a CL implementation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`(integer-length most-negative-fixnum)` will tell you.

Comment: Thanks. Clozure CL on my 64-bit openSUSE shows 60, so 4 bits are reserved for flags.