# Is it possible to safely assume that the 16 high bits (2 are sufficient for me) in a 64-bit pointer are unset?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, bit-manipulation, x86-64, virtual-address-space

I'm building a data structure which sets into 64 bit integers a set bit every 2 or 3 bits.

It would be convenient for me if I could alternately also store a pointer in this structure (when they are terminal nodes in a tree, but that's not relevant).

For the purposes of my representation (which guarantees either the highest or second highest bit are set), if it can be assumed that pointers never have their highest two bits set, i.e. this assertion holds:

```
void *sixty_four_bit_pointer = a_valid_address(); 
bool always_zero = 0xC000000000000000 & sixty_four_bit_pointer;
```

then I can do this trick!

Comment: Nope, I've seen Linux use random starting offsets that use the whole 64-bits.

Comment: Okay I guess I'll have to tack on another field in my struct.

Comment: I read somewhere that some processors have traps explicitly to prevent use of the upper bits for other purposes.

Comment: It's pretty common to make the assumption that pointers (at least, to things which need alignment) have their low 2 or 3 bits cleared. That hack goes back at least to early Lisp implementations, which is, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106597/why-are-fixnums-in-emacs-only-29-bits

Comment: Oh actually... I never thought about the other end of the pointer! That might do the trick. Might a `char *` potentially not be aligned?

Comment: `char` does not require alignment. You either need a data type that is 8-byte aligned, or you can artificially align your pointers.

Comment: You can use the low 2 or 3 bits. [Using the extra 16 bits in 64-bit pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18426582/995714)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not safe in general. It's programs that pull tricks like this that led to the `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` flag in Windows. (Aka "this is why we can't have nice things.")

What you can do is use the bottom bits instead of the top bits. Since your structure contains a pointer, it is already 8-byte aligned, which means that the bottom three bits are always 0, so you can use those bits as tag bits.

Comment: It's that the pointer's type must be one that must be 8-byte aligned for me to then be sure that it has three unset low bits. i.e. you're assuming my pointer is a pointer to that struct. Yes? Like, I can't assume a `char*` has low 3 bits unset, but I can assume a `uint64_t*` does.

Comment: It wasn't clear what the pointer was a pointer to. I thought it was a pointer to your structure (which in turn contains more pointers to other nodes). If it's just a `char *` then you will need to impose the external alignment yourself. (I.e., make sure your `char *` pointers are 8-byte aligned.)